# how to center two divs in Bootstrap 5 where one div contains an input and another div contains a button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have an input and a button on the same line I would like to leave it centered in a div in the center of the page, as shown in the attached image, it contains an input to insert the email and a button more are aligned on the left of the page I would like to move to the center.
[image: imagem com um input de email e um botão de submit alinhados na esquerda]

```
<div class="row g-6 text-center">
                        
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="email" style="text-align:left" class="form-control pl-2 shadow-none">
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
          <button class="btn btn-block btn-dark" type="submit">INSCREVER-SE!</button>
        </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the content by adding the `justify-content-center` class to the row div like this:

```html
<div class="row g-6 text-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input
      type="email"
      style="text-align: left"
      class="form-control pl-2 shadow-none"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="col-auto">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-dark" type="submit">
      INSCREVER-SE!
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-drknr7?file=index.html

PD: I understand that we may come from different backgrounds and speak different languages, but would be highly appreciated if you posted in English, so everyone can participate in the conversation :)